What does the superscript $3$ in $d^3x$ mean in an integral?
At the risk of seeming ignorant, please explain what does the superscript $3$ in $d^3x$ mean in the integrals  5.12, 5.13, 5.14, 5.15? Why 3? Why there is no such in the 5.10 integral?


That is just trying to tell you that those are 3D integrals v.s. 1d

@naturallyInconsistent That is to say that the result of those integrals is a 3D vector? But the 5.10 also gives a vector.

No, when you do a volume integral, i.e. 3D integral, you can get anything. If the integrand is a scalar density, you will get a scalar. If the integrand is a vector density, then you can get back a vector. The two 1D integrals in Equation (5.10) gives a vector back because of the $\vec x_{12}$ in the numerator.

The infinitesimals in a dot product in (5.10) each pair with a $\oint$ line integration operator, which is not the same thing as volume integration, even though each contour is embedded in three-dimensional space.

This is one way to do notation for triple integrals, also known as three-dimensional integrals. Think of it as shorthand for something like $$\int \cdots \mathrm d^3x=\int\int\int\cdots\mathrm d\ldots\mathrm d\ldots\mathrm d\ldots.$$
You can ommit this "power of three" symbolism by using a vector $\mathbf x$ as your integration variable, perhaps written with vector bracket notation. Something like this: $$\int \cdots \mathrm d^3 x=\int \cdots \mathrm d\mathbf x=\int\cdots \mathrm d(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\int\int\int\cdots\mathrm d\ldots\mathrm d\ldots\mathrm d\ldots.$$

Thank you for the answer, but I actually got it checking in other books. The difference between 5.10 and 5.14 is that in 5.10 current I is used, while in 5.14 current density J is used. If I is used, it is a line integral. If J is used, it must be a volume integral, where $d^3$ is required.
